# How to get trans_primitives of highest entity in featuretools?

Tags: python, feature-engineering, featuretools

In the classic mock customer dataset example in featuretools, if I have to derive `trans_primitives` like `month, day, year` etc. of `transaction_time` attribute of `transactions entity`. How do I do that?

[image]

```
import featuretools as ft
es = ft.demo.load_mock_customer(return_entityset=True)
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es, target_entity=???, agg_primitives=["count"], trans_primitives=["month"], max_depth=1)
```

What should be the target entity in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question! You can get those features from the transaction time by setting the target entity to `transactions` in DFS. You also want to specify which transform primitives to apply. Let me know if this helps.

```py
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_entity='transactions',
    agg_primitives=[],
    trans_primitives=['day', 'month', 'year'],
    max_depth=1,
)

feature_matrix.head().filter(regex='time')
```

```
                DAY(transaction_time)  MONTH(transaction_time)  YEAR(transaction_time)
transaction_id
298                                 1                        1                    2014
2                                   1                        1                    2014
308                                 1                        1                    2014
116                                 1                        1                    2014
371                                 1                        1                    2014
```